# Bytecode compilation errors

Tags: java, bytecode

I am using the program JBE (Java Bytecode Editor) http://set.ee/jbe
I have the following bytecode but it keeps outputting errors due to

```
Error: Argument type error at line 53, instruction "ldc"
Error: Syntax error at line 54, instruction """
Error: Argument type error at line 100, instruction "ldc"
Error: Syntax error at line 101, instruction """
Error: Argument type error at line 154, instruction "ldc"
Error: Syntax error at line 155, instruction """
Error: Argument type error at line 206, instruction "ldc"
Error: Syntax error at line 207, instruction """
```

for example the first 2 errors refer to

```
ldc ");
"
```

I understand as to why this is causing an error but how do I insert a \r\n at the end

the instructions

```
getstatic BlockResources/instance LBlockResources;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetTypeID()I
invokevirtual BlockResources/getTextureMappingData(I)LTextureMappingData;
astore_2
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetMeta()I
ifne 103
iload_1
ifeq 57
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
ldc "       world.setBlockWithNotify(i + "
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetX()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", j + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetY()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", k + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetZ()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_2
ifnull 39
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ifnull 39
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ldc ""
if_acmpne 43
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetTypeID()I
invokestatic java/lang/Integer/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
goto 52
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
invokestatic java/lang/String/valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
ldc ".blockID"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ");
"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
areturn
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
ldc "       world.setBlock(i + "
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetX()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", j + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetY()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", k + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetZ()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_2
ifnull 85
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ifnull 85
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ldc ""
if_acmpne 89
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetTypeID()I
invokestatic java/lang/Integer/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
goto 98
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
invokestatic java/lang/String/valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
ldc ".blockID"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ");
"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
areturn
iload_1
ifeq 156
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
ldc "       world.setBlockAndMetadataWithNotify(i + "
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetX()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", j + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetY()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", k + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetZ()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_2
ifnull 133
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ifnull 133
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ldc ""
if_acmpne 137
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetTypeID()I
invokestatic java/lang/Integer/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
goto 146
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
invokestatic java/lang/String/valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
ldc ".blockID"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetMeta()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ");
"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
areturn
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
ldc "       world.setBlockAndMetadata(i + "
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetX()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", j + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetY()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", k + "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetZ()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_2
ifnull 184
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ifnull 184
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
ldc ""
if_acmpne 188
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetTypeID()I
invokestatic java/lang/Integer/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
goto 197
new java/lang/StringBuilder
dup
aload_2
invokevirtual TextureMappingData/getSpawnCode()Ljava/lang/String;
invokestatic java/lang/String/valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
ldc ".blockID"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ", "
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_0
invokevirtual BlockBase/GetMeta()I
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ldc ");
"
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
areturn
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it in JBE, but you can easily do string escaping in Krakatau.

Answer (score 0):

it's as simple as you wrote. For example amend line 53 to `ldc ");\r\n"`

Comment: ldc ");\r\n" is a string not a carriage return

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your question.
you could: change the code of `JAsmParser.java` and add at line 43 (before the line //switchmode...) `fullInstr = fullInstr.replaceAll("\\\\r", "\r");` and `fullInstr = fullInstr.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");` or you add two char's to the StringBuilder in the Code Editor `aload_2
bipush 13
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
pop` and `aload_2
bipush 10
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
pop`. Probably there is a better solution in the code. This was found after a quick view over it.